# How to hide toolbar in some fragments or open some fragments in full screen mode

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am able to hide the toolbar in a fragment using this code:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

But the problem is that when I press the back button to come from another fragment, the toolbar is also not showing in that fragment.

How do I over come this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put 
`((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();`

in `onResume()` of fragments you want to hide and

`((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();`

in onResume() of other fragments which belong to same activity.
OR
put it in `onStop()` of your current fragment.

Comment: I tried the onResume and onStop approach and the toolbar still hidden in the next fragment. @AbhishekBansal

Comment: @FelipeBelluco there is very less info available to answer your question